# I2C ACKEN Bit doesnt get cleared by hardware

Tags: c, pic, i2c

I am using a PIC16F1789 and an MPU-9250. The Code inside my I2C Reading funciton looks like this:

```
unsigned char i2cSensor_Read(unsigned char regAddr){
unsigned char val;
// Start
i2cWait();
SEN = 1;

// Address + Write Bit
i2cWait();
SSP1BUF = ((slvAdd<<1) | (0b0<<0)); // address slave + write (0)
i2cWait();

//Register address
SSP1BUF = regAddr; // address register
i2cWait();

//Start
RSEN = 1;
i2cWait();

// Address + Read Bit
SSP1BUF = ((slvAdd<<1) | (0b1<<0)); //Address + read (1)
i2cWait();

// Read data
RCEN = 1;
i2cWait();
val = SSP1BUF;

ACKDT = 1; // set acknowlege Bit (1 = Not Acknowlege, 0 = Acknowlege)
ACKEN = 1; // send acknowlege Bit

// Stop
i2cWait();
PEN = 1;
return val;
```

`}`

When calling the last i2cWait(), the program hangs.
The wait function looks like this:

```
void i2cWait(){
while((SSP1STAT & 0x04) || (SSP1CON2 & 0x1F));
}
```

I've worked with the "Single-Byte Read Sequence" on page 35 of the 9250 Datasheet: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/learn_tutorials/5/5/0/MPU9250REV1.0.pdf

And the PIC Datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001675C.pdf

When debugging, the program gets stuck in the i2cWait() after I send the NACK Bit. It gets stuck because the ACKEN Bit (Bit 4) of the SSPCON2 register (Page 341 of PIC datasheet) doesn't get cleared, so the program gets stuck in the while().

Why is this the case? Does the Slave have to clear this bit? Is the slave device broken?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is really the BF flag is still set and not allowing the ack to be clocked out.  As soon as you set RCEN, the BF flag is cleared, thus the call to wait does nothing and val probably contains old data, not new.  After 8 clocks, the BF flag is then set and SSP1BUF has the new data.  Again, the issue is that BF is set because you didn't read the data buffer after receiving the data, thus the baud rate generator (clock source) is suspended:

> "the contents of the SSPSR are loaded into the SSPBUF, the BF flag bit
>   is set, the SSP1IF flag bit is set and the Baud Rate Generator is
>   suspended from counting, holding SCL low. The MSSP is now in Idle
>   state awaiting the next command. When the buffer is read by the CPU,
>   the BF flag bit is automatically cleared. The user can then send an
>   Acknowledge bit at the end of reception by setting the Acknowledge
>   Sequence Enable, ACKEN bit of the SSPCON2 register."

To fix this, you should poll the BF flag looking for a true after you write RCEN.

There are other issues, such as the wait after writing to SEN probably does nothing either, since writing to SEN only SSP1IF bit (SSP1IF is set by hardware on completion of the Start. )